# Error while extracting number from a string in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am processing columns in a loop

```
    'US-Eco.Metric8_MomChg'.'US-Eco.Metric9_MomChg','US-Eco.Metric10_MomChg'
```

I need to extract the integer from the strings and save it in a array. I am using following code, but getting an error. Please help me.

```
  for col in self.columns[]:
   country, market = col.split('-')
   num = []
   num.append([int (s) for market in str.split() if market.isdigit ()])
```

Error message:

```
   TypeError: descriptor 'split' of 'str' object needs an argument
```

Expected output:

```
    [8,9,10]
```

Comment: What's the error? Please make sure you're including all relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you intended was something like `num = [int(s) for s in market if s.isdigit()]`. But that would extract each digit of number separately.

Instead, use `re.findall` to extract all numbers in string format and then use `int` method to convert them to numbers

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "'US-Eco.Metric8_MomChg'.'US-Eco.Metric9_MomChg','US-Eco.Metric10_MomChg'"
>>> list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', s)))
[8, 9, 10]
```